# Postgresql - unable to connect to database: could not connect to server: No such file or directory

Tags: postgresql, ansible

So I'm trying to create a Postgres Database on my remote server with Ansible, unfortunately I'm getting this error message

```
TASK [postgresql : Create database with name sola] *****************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was:    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
fatal: [some-remote-server]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false
}

MSG:

unable to connect to database: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

This would be my playbook

```
- name: enable the PostgreSQL package repository
  copy:
    src: pgdg-96-redhat.repo
    dest: /etc/yum.repos.d/pgdg-96-redhat.repo

- name: install additional packages
  yum:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
  - "{{ packages }}"

- name: Ensure bash and OpenSSL are the  latest version
  yum:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    update_cache: true
    state: latest
  with_items:
    - bash
    - openssl
  tags: packages

- name: install system packages
  yum:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: installed
  with_items:
    - "{{ packages }}"
  become: yes

- name: Install PostgreSQL
  yum:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    update_cache: true
    state: installed
  with_items:
    - postgresql
    - postgresql-contrib
    - python-psycopg2
  tags: packages
  become: yes

- name: enabling postgresql services
  service:
    name: postgresql
    state: started
    enabled: yes

- name: Create database with name sola
  postgresql_db:
    name: sola
    encoding: 'UTF-8'
    lc_collate: 'en_US.UTF-8'
    lc_ctype: 'en_US.UTF-8'
    template: 'template0'

- name: Ensure database is created
  sudo_user: postgres
  postgresql_db:
    name: dbname
    encoding: 'UTF-8'
    lc_collate: 'en_US.UTF-8'
    lc_ctype: 'en_US.UTF-8'
    template: 'template0'
    state: present
```

My suspicions are, that either something went wrong witht the installation process, so that postgres hasn't even been properly installed on the remote server or that I'm not properly enabling and starting the postgres services. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: is postgresql running and socket `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432` exists?

Comment: Postgres is not running and I believe the socket does exist